# Tor configuration stuck 100%

Tags: configuration

When I type tor in terminal (macOSX), I get this. I want to configure tor but the thing is it gets stuck at 100% and nothing happens then. But the terminal still runs so I assume that it's doing something but nothing happens.

```
Last login: Wed Apr  3 11:46:47 on ttys000
yuvrajs-MacBook-Pro:~ yuvrajsingh$ killall tor
yuvrajs-MacBook-Pro:~ yuvrajsingh$ tor
Apr 03 11:58:21.244 [notice] Tor 0.3.5.8 running on Darwin with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2r, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma N/A, and Libzstd N/A.
Apr 03 11:58:21.244 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Apr 03 11:58:21.244 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc".
Apr 03 11:58:21.247 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 03 11:58:21.247 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 03 11:58:21.247 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Apr 03 11:58:21.247 [notice] Opened Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Apr 03 11:58:21.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/local/Cellar/tor/0.3.5.8/share/tor/geoip.
Apr 03 11:58:21.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/local/Cellar/tor/0.3.5.8/share/tor/geoip6.
Apr 03 11:58:21.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Apr 03 11:58:21.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
Apr 03 11:58:22.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
Apr 03 11:58:22.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Apr 03 11:58:22.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Apr 03 11:58:23.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The tor program is different from the Tor Browser. If you’re trying to run the tor program, your results look normal since the SOCKS proxy is now running, but if you’re trying to run the Tor Browser, that is a different program you need to download and install. You can configure tor by editing the `torrc` file before starting tor.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty much expected. When I compare this to my Docker-Containers (based on Debian), then is is the last line in my tor-log-file.

Please check via netstat, if tor made any connections. These additional connections are necessary, but for some reason not displayed by tor.

Also maybe you should run

```
tor &
```

so that tor runs in the background. This enables you to use the terminal, after tor was started / bootstrapped. Alternatively you could also open up a second terminal and check for connections there.

As @steve already mentioned it is hard to tell what you want to do, if you don't tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your Tor instance has been bootstrapped up successfully and it's awaiting your requests and the network messages from outside. In time, like in 24 hours, another stats will be printed into the standard output. Only if there are some errors occurred - they will be printed before stats. It's totally OK

Answer (score 0):

Example torrc:

````
    User tor
    PIDFile /var/run/tor/tor.pid
    ExcludeExitNodes {RU},{UA},{AM},{KG},{BY}
    StrictNodes 1
    #TransPort 0.0.0.0:9141
    MaxCircuitDirtiness 600
    ExitRelay 0
    ExitPolicy reject *:*
    ExitPolicy reject6 *:*
    #GeoIPFile /opt/share/tor/geoip
    #GeoIPv6File /opt/share/tor/geoip6
    DataDirectory /var/lib/tor/data
    VirtualAddrNetwork 10.254.0.0/16
    DNSPort 127.0.0.1:9053
    AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
    UseBridges 1
    ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy managed
    
    Bridge obfs4 185.177.207.136:8443 929EE56F32F46A9B7DC9EDBE5B20B07A6DDE684A cert=YCE03UX5zWFYWhQag7yN8ObKJgTM+p+RAFugyOR/gziEpZ5tIJ7SeAhpOu0B92+JjGcqEw iat-mode=0
    Bridge obfs4 15.235.46.239:8542 7213CFFDEBBD6101D72FD161FB8F11EFF0010B75 cert=S91AmAe86ZX0lAhcw+YQY0nZafg46FnDcZ1MCHbHq+Gan+Cp7VQtkcjwY80hpvarpevdPA iat-mode=0
    Bridge obfs4 45.32.230.154:443 1B95B8500E8D8FE87DDE66E25038ECA48D38EF72 cert=jVIYtwqwaFvDiR/jvQxTVLSwURMGdDIJgYh+GTLYWxeGdNHPn2oNCDiBcLlzsKZvQMrmOQ iat-mode=0
    Bridge obfs4 70.34.244.140:443 B80CB82C1F927579B1734F877A37DB2F4C928C39 cert=KHReofcW7JvO3PUVT8YhIa1ptIedcxpRG/tv6APa7Ph9yfooyNWOYaLiggDggnJQvxEmIw iat-mode=0
    
    #RESERVE
    #Bridge obfs4 88.152.174.56:12457 63EC75D21DC4301F7BB805B0794F9DAD2892AC09 cert=b9WUo0macm4tNq6HVpJnBTjX/KNOnf0Vw70FKbnFFl+6njXInpuHCqjvMMYEMovRul7DbQ iat-mode=0
    #Bridge obfs4 95.217.122.172:990 064C81E12B6BF387804E8F6D85C8FA3E5E193311 cert=JNqV9XG7KfWeZllUuZqw1MbiEjBB7w6N+UGlOFaRX18j6cQ7jBmBnYAhQ06Cpu81dbWULg iat-mode=0
    #Bridge obfs4 213.232.255.61:443 2387004AE19179F6685EA4BE13876B813F823507 cert=vCjBrF2ZtwNbTFaGO/yfsibtOOvI+CWdWM71kP7MRvG6jqS492mRiUAei3jdcaPNdw9GZQ iat-mode=0```
````